# XPath, how to select nodes based in 2 conditions with attribute dependency

Tags: xml, xpath

I'm struggling to merge 2 conditions in my XPath query with attribute dependence.

I want to select all the nodes with AdjsCI = 4005 and AdjsRNCid=280

```
<managedObject class="ADJS">
  <p name="AdjsCI">4005</p>
  <p name="AdjsRNCid">280</p>
</managedObject>
```

For a single condition it works fine, but I don't find for 2.

With 1 condition:

SelectNodes("//managedObject/p[@name='AdjsCI'][text()='4005']");

This one is OK.

But with 2 I've tried many many options but none worked.

SelectNodes("//managedObject/p[@name='AdjsCI' and @name='AdjsRNCid][text()='4005' and text()='280']");

SelectNodes("//managedObject/p[[@name='AdjsCI'][text()='4005] and [@name='AdjsRNCid][text()='280']]");

SelectNodes("//managedObject/p[@name='AdjsCI'][text()='4005'] and //managedObject/p[@name='AdjsRNCid'][text()='280']");

Is there a solution for this?

Thank you very much in advance.

João Paulo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track. You need to put the `and` **within** the predicate (the `[]` condition), being sure to have it relative to the node being considered:

```
//managedObject[p[@name='AdjsCI']=4005 and p[@name='AdjsRNCid']=280]
```

Note that in cases such as yours where the entirety of the element's contents is what you're comaparing against, you don't need `text()`.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options purely based on the xml in the question.

1.

```
SelectNodes("//managedObject/p[contains(@name,'Adjs') and (text()='4005' or text()='280')]");
```

2.

```
SelectNodes("//managedObject/p[(@name,'AdjsCI' or @name='AdjsRNCid') and (text()='4005' or text()='280')]");
```

  3.

You can make the xpath more generic if you want to select the nodes without the data dependency. For example,

```
SelectNodes("//managedObject/p[contains(@name,'Adjs'));
```

This will select any node that contains Ajds in the name attribute.

There are more options such as regular expressions that can be used as well. But this should address the issue you're facing for the moment.

Comment: Hello Sai, thank you for the fast reply but none is working. The first one is giving 91 results and I should get only 2. In fact I want to find all the nodes with LAC = 1800 and CI = 4005. With your option 1 I get all the cells with LAC 1800. The second options leads to excetion: Unhandled Exception: System.Xml.XPath.XPathException: '//managedObject/p[(@name
'AdjsCI' or @name='AdjsLAC') and (text()='4005' or text()='1800')]' has an invalid token. I change @name='AdjsCI' and then no exception but still 91 as result. If I put text()='4005' and text()='1800' I got 0 :/